# Converting string to DateTime safely

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I have a string that came from a Database, but I´m not sure that will be a valid dateTime.

First I´m trying to validate if it´s null,

then if not null I want to safely convert it to DateTime because I´m not sure that a row["a"].ToString will be a valid DateTime

```
output.limitExpiryDate = row["a"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.Now : "something to convert here";
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.TryParse`:

```
output.limitExpiryDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime limitExpiryDate;
if(row["a"] != DBNull.Value && DateTime.TryParse(row.Field<string>("a"), out limitExpiryDate))
    output.limitExpiryDate = limitExpiryDate;
```

It it was a nullable `DateTime` column you could use the [`Field` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) that supports nullable types:

```
DateTime? limitExpiryDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("a");
if(limitExpiryDate.HasValue)
    output.limitExpiryDate = limitExpiryDate.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  var format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
 output.limitExpiryDate = row["a"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.Now : DateTime.ParseExact(row["a"], format, provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
if (row["a"] != null && row["a"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(row["a"], out date))
        date = DateTime.Now;
}

output.limitExpiryDate = date;
```

or you can use `TryParseExact` and specify format, if you know what datetime format your `row["a"]` has.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this. It doesnt give any problem for any date format. It works for me.

```
public static DateTime? ToDateTime(this string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return Convert.ToDateTime(value);
}
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing [`String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-7.0)? This answer also does not address `DBNull`, which is not the same thing as `null`. You also state this code "doesnt any problem for any date format", which is objectively not true.

Comment: Yes, doesn't need my string extension. I edited it now. I can say this code doesn't give error for any date format. If you think that it is wrong please answer it.

Comment: There's a lot of different ways to format a date and time, and `Convert.ToDateTime` depends on the current computer's Culture. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q8XIbA